# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Tags: javascript, mocha, npm

I do not understand why I am having a syntax error? I am trying to run my test javascript which is available here

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

let accounts;

beforeEach(() => {
    // Get list of all accounts
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    // Use one of those accounts to deploy the contract
});

describe('Inbox', ()=>{
    it('deploys a contract', ()=> {
        console.log(accounts);
    });
} );
```

I am getting this error when I am running "npm run test" on PowerShell

```
> inbox@1.0.0 test C:\inbox
> mocha


C:\inbox\test\Inbox.test.js:10
        accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
                   ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:199:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:169:25)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:177:24)
    at async formattedImport (C:\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:7:14)
    at async Object.exports.requireOrImport (C:\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:48:32)
    at async Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (C:\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:73:20)
    at async singleRun (C:\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:125:3)
    at async Object.exports.handler (C:\inbox\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:366:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! inbox@1.0.0 test: `mocha`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the inbox@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-23T14_04_34_840Z-debug.log
PS C:\inbox>
```

Can someone help me understand how I could resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change the fallback method inside beforeEach to be an async method as follows:

```js
beforeEach(async() => {
    // Get list of all accounts
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    // Use one of those accounts to deploy the contract
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this support, I think I still am lacking knowledge in JavaScript. 
Thanks for pointing this out. May you help me understand why peers here voted me negative. I think maybe because my question turned out to be so simple. But I am learning, I wonder why couldn't they be more supportive rather than aggressive.

Comment: It is because it isn't relevant to this particular stack exchange which is about ethereum and your question is specifically about javascript. Don't be disheartened 
by a downvote - it is more a way to organise useful  / pertinent information.  If you are moving into this space though I would advise to look at async methods in javascript and why they are useful.

Comment: @rsc05 Actually, I was the one who downvoted it for the reasons HAS-Jack mentioned. Don't take it to heart, this is for the better of this community.

Comment: @rsc05 I suggest you read more about synchronous and asynchronous JavaScript. I was where you are right now just a couple of years ago, and I kinda envy you since I'll never get to learn this stuff for the first time again.